# Assigning a child class object to an object of the parent class

Tags: java, sockets, networking, parent-child, subclass

I'm implementing a network library that I've been working on, and I'm having difficulty with one of the server systems.

In the library, I have a class called `ConnectedClient` that is created when a remote client connects to the server. In other words, when a server receives a connection, it creates a `ConnectedClient` object, and passes that object to an overridden method.

Here is the relevant server code:

```
public void run() {
        if (IsConnectionActive()) {
            System.err.println("Cannot initialize server. Server is already running: " + serverSocket);
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Initializing multiclient server...");
        try {
            Init();
            System.out.println("Server Initialized.");
            threadActive = true;
        } catch (ServerInitializeException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Waiting for client connections...");

        while (threadActive) {
            try {
                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                ConnectedClient temp = new ConnectedClient(s);
                connectedClients.add(temp);
                System.out.println("Client connection caught and initialized. Client: " + s);
                System.out.println("Connection with " + s + " now listening for incoming packets.");
                ThreadAction(temp);
                CleanClientList();
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error accepting a client. Connection refused and reset.");
            } catch (ConnectionInitializationException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " Connection refused and reset.");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ThreadAction(ConnectedClient client) {

    }
```

The method `ThreadAction` is overridden by an end user client, and that is how new connections are accepted.

And here is the `ConnectedClient` code:

```
public class ConnectedClient extends Connection implements Runnable {

    public ConnectedClient(Socket socket) throws ConnectionInitializationException {
        connectedSocket = socket;
        OpenIOStreams();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (IsConnectionActive()) {
            try {
                ThreadAction(ReceivePacket());
            } catch (ReadPacketException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " Closing connection.");
                try {
                    CloseIOStreams();
                } catch (ConnectionException e1) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ThreadAction(Packet p) {
        if (p.packetType == Packet.PACKET_TYPE.Message)
            System.out.println(p.packetString);
        else if (p.packetType == Packet.PACKET_TYPE.CloseConnection) {
            System.out.println("Client wishes to close connection. Closing.");
            try {
                CloseIOStreams();
            } catch (ConnectionException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

*The class `Connection` that it extends is simply a blueprint containing several more variables

In implementation, I have the server method overridden, as shown here:

```
public Server(int port) {
        super(port);
        clients = new ArrayList<ClientConnection>();
        clientThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    }

    @Override
    public void ThreadAction(ConnectedClient cc) {
        // ClientConnection temp = (ClientConnection) cc;
        // clients.add(temp);



        Thread t = new Thread(cc);
        clientThreads.add(t);
        t.start();
    }
```

This all works, I'm able to access the `ConnectedClient` object within my server, send and receive default messages, etc. However, the issue comes in when I try to modify my `ConnectedClient ThreadAction(Packet)` method. At first, I tried to create an extension of the `ConnectedClient` class, here:

```
public class ClientConnection extends ConnectedClient {

    public ClientConnection(Socket socket) throws ConnectionInitializationException {
        super(socket);
    }

    @Override
    public void ThreadAction(Packet p) {

    }

}
```

However, when I tried to assign a new object to the passed object in my server `ThreadAction(Packet)` method (as shown in my comments within that method), an exception was thrown saying that I cannot cast `ConnectedClient` to `ClientConnection`.

So, how can I override my `ConnectedClient ThreadAction(Packet)` method, and use it with passed objects within my server? For example, if I want my `ConnectedClient ThreadAction(Packet)` to print out "packet received" every time a client sends a packet to the server, instead of the packet's message, how can I override the method to do so, without changing the library?

Sorry if I'm being unclear, or not providing enough information, I'm slightly flustered as I've been working on this issue for a couple days now and it's gotten the better of me. I can provide additional information if needed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You say `when I tried to assign a new object to the passed object in my server ThreadAction(Packet) method`. Packet is the passed object? Actually you do not assign a new object to Packet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I tried to assign a new object to the passed object in my server ThreadAction(Packet) method (as shown in my comments within that method), an exception was thrown saying that I cannot cast ConnectedClient to ClientConnection.

You **can't** cast `ConnectedClient` to `ClientConnection`. `ClientConnection` is a child class of `ConnectedClient`, and therefor it's impossible to cast - you can only cast one object to another if you're casting to a parent object. That is, you can only cast `ClientConnection` to `ConnectedClient`.

Think of the classes `java.lang.String` and `java.lang.Object`. You can cast a `String` to `Object` because `String` is a child class of object, and is therefor an `Object`, you can't cast `Object` to `String` because it's impossible to verify if the `Object` is indeed a `String`. This is why you can't cast your objects.

---

What you're going to have to do is create a method that can convert the two. This method should take in a `ConnectedClient`, and return a `ClientConnection`.

```
public static ClientConnection conntectedClientToClientConnection(ConnectedClient client){
    //Make a ClientConnection that represents the ConnectionClient object
    //Return it
}
```

You could also make a constructor in `ClientConnection` that accepts a `ConnectionClient`.

Inside the method/constructor, you will need to "copy the variables". That is, make sure all the variables inside the `ClientConnection` object are the same as the variables inside the `ConnectionClient` object.

---

Another thing you can try is change your code in the server code class.

Change this:

```
Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
ConnectedClient temp = new ConnectedClient(s);
connectedClients.add(temp);
System.out.println("Client connection caught and initialized. Client: " + s);
System.out.println("Connection with " + s + " now listening for incoming packets.");
ThreadAction(temp);
CleanClientList();
```

To this:

```
Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
ClientConnection temp = new ClientConnection(s); //Changed this line
connectedClients.add(temp);
System.out.println("Client connection caught and initialized. Client: " + s);
System.out.println("Connection with " + s + " now listening for incoming packets.");
ThreadAction(temp);
CleanClientList();
```

This will do what you're asking, provided that the `ClientConnection` class also has a constructor that accepts a socket.

Comment: Sadly I think this is probably the best option... I'm really trying to find a way to have it implement simpler. My clients, server(s), and core objects are very intuitive to use and run, but the connected client is the problem child (sadly)... I'll give this a shot and hope for the best. If I dont have any other answers in a couple day's I'll accept yours

Comment: @PulsePanda I know it sounds rather daunting, but with reflection it could actually be quite easy. If the variables aren't too complex, you could iterate over the variables and assign them reflection. I'm sorry I couldn't provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change following `server` code:

```
ConnectedClient temp = new ConnectedClient(s);
connectedClients.add(temp);
System.out.println("Client connection caught and initialized. Client: " + s);
System.out.println("Connection with " + s + " now listening for incoming packets.");
ThreadAction(temp);
```

to:

```
ClientConnection temp = new ClientConnection(s); // only this is changed
connectedClients.add(temp);
System.out.println("Client connection caught and initialized. Client: " + s);
System.out.println("Connection with " + s + " now listening for incoming packets.");
ThreadAction(temp);
```

I do not think you will get: `cannot cast ConnectedClient to ClientConnection` after the change. You may override `ClientConnection.ThreadAction` in your own way. Please tell me it works or not.

Comment: I cant make that change because the server code is a separate library, that I'm testing. I'm trying to implement it from an external client point of view to find any issues and bugs with it. Otherwise, that would totally work, but I dont have access to that server code